# PassportJS to get Facebook User Location

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, passport.js

I've attempted to set my strategy to get a user's home in two ways, and neither of which work.  Does anyone have code for PassportJS to get a user's address (just city and state)?

Strategy attempting both "location" and "address":

```
profileFields: ['id', 'name','picture.type(large)', 'emails', 'displayName', 'location', 'address', 'about', 'gender'],
```

Attempting to get using address as seen here [portablecontacts.net](http://portablecontacts.net/draft-spec.html#schema):

```
 user.facebook.location = profile.address.locality + ', ' profile.address.region;
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Simpler answer

Those location fields not yet mapped in the code from their Portable Contacts schema to Facebook's own schema. You can see that map [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/blob/master/lib/strategy.js#L212) (and the absence of those two fields).

Instead, simply use the Facebook schema directly. So the profileFields array should include the `location` field, then when you call authenticate, you need to request that field from Facebook:

```
passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_location'] }));
```

Note that in the scope array, it is referred to as `user_location` but in the profileFields array it is just `location`

Answer (score 0):

It's not working when use it in scope, use in declaration strategy instead

`passport.use(new fbStrategy({
    clientID: fbClientId,
    clientSecret: fbClientSecret,
    callbackURL: fbCallback,
    profileFields: [
        'location', // <- HERE
        'email', 'first_name','last_name',
        'picture.type(large)', 'link'
    ]
    }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
          ....
    })
)`